# How do I trace a Linux command in terminal to see which files it uses as it executes?

Tags: linux, terminal, command

I want to know what files, system and non-system files, a command uses as it is being run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run it with `strace -e file`:

```
strace -e file /path/to/command
```

This will list all system calls involving a file name on standard error. You can output the list to a file instead using the `-o` option:

```
strace -e file -o filesyscalls.txt /path/to/command
```

Comment: Just a caveat, this will not work on setuid or setgid programs. You might also want to add `-f` if you need to follow forked processes.